# Add CSS class to element based on the ID and a specific attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I want to add a new `class` to `body` if an `id` has a specific `style` attribute using `jQuery`.
Why is this code not working?

```
if ($('#myID').css('display') == 'none'){
  $('body').addClass('loaded');
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does the HTML for `#myID` look like? When/how do you run that code?

Comment: Assuming the element exists when you run this code it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/3g05qbnr/ There must be some other underlying issue.

Comment: Probably classic case of "Running before the element exists"

Comment: The ID is part of an preloader. The style attribute "display: none" is only added when the website is fully loaded.
I need to add an class to the body after the preloader is hidden.

Comment: @epascarello That makes sense. Is there a way to constantly check if the id has the style attribute?

Comment: Does the preloader library expose any events you can hook to once loading is complete? If not, I'd suggest finding one that does as it's by far the best way to do what you need

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I don't want to change the preloader. The only thing thats changes really when the loading is complete is that "display: none" is added to the id

Comment: The issue is that you have no way of knowing when that happens. If the library is created properly it should raise an event so you can hook your own code to execute when loading completes. If it doesn't then you'll have to use something like a MutationObserver, but that's not performant and is a bit of an ugly solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It works when I constantly check and not only once:

```
function check_loader(){
      if ($('#ple-loader-wraps99').css('display') == 'none'){
        $('body').addClass('loaded');
      };};
window.setInterval(check_loader,1000);
```

Comment: So your interval is going to run forever, even after the class has been added?  Consider using a recursive timeout instead.

Comment: @Taplar Okay thank you. Do you have an example? Maybe I can make an "if true " statement to end the function?

Comment: @Taplar Thank you! I will try it out later

Comment: Or you could just store your interval id (returned from `setInterval`) and then clearInterval when your condition is met. https://jsfiddle.net/bfqj194s/

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for DOM changes on a specific DOM node using the `MutationObserver` API, then trigger an action:

```js
const targetNode = document.getElementById('my-id');

// Specify which mutations to observe (options)
const config = { attributes: true };

// Simulate the preloader action (webpage load)
setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelector('#my-id').style ='display: none;'
}, 1000)

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = function (mutationsList, observer) {

  console.log(`Mutation type: ${mutationsList[0].type}`)
  console.log(`ID ${mutationsList[0].target.id}`);
  
  // Make the necessary changes to your target elements here
  document.querySelector('body').classList.add('loaded');

};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

```css
.loaded {
  background-color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-id">Loading..</div>
```

**Note: All code is Vanilla JS (no jQuery).**

Example created using code from the [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)